# Got Unauthorization Error when create Azure Task Automation

Tags: azure, ubuntu, virtual-machine, azure-automation, azure-authentication

I'm create two automation task via menu virtual machine -> automation -> task. One for start the virtual machine and other one for deallocate it.

When it executes I got the below error:

{
"statusCode": 401,
"headers": {
"Pragma": "no-cache",
"x-ms-failure-cause": "gateway",
"x-ms-request-id": "7aa2d0bd-cd4a-40dc-9a60-181ee780a36f",
"x-ms-correlation-request-id": "7aa2d0bd-cd4a-40dc-9a60-181ee780a36f",
"x-ms-routing-request-id": "SOUTHCENTRALUS:20211117T090000Z:7aa2d0bd-cd4a-40dc-9a60-181ee780a36f",
"Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
"X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
"Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
"x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "false",
"Cache-Control": "no-cache",
"Date": "Wed, 17 Nov 2021 08:59:59 GMT",
"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/a23894c2-33fb-4084-b7fd-7dc06bdd042e", error="invalid_token", error_description="The access token is from the wrong issuer. It must match the tenant associated with this subscription. Please use correct authority to get the token."",
"Content-Length": "702",
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Expires": "-1"
},
"body": {
"error": {
"code": "InvalidAuthenticationTokenTenant",
"message": "The access token is from the wrong issuer 'https://sts.windows.net/f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a/'. It must match the tenant 'https://sts.windows.net/a23894c2-33fb-4084-b7fd-7dc06bdd042e/' associated with this subscription. Please use the authority (URL) 'https://login.windows.net/a23894c2-33fb-4084-b7fd-7dc06bdd042e' to get the token. Note, if the subscription is transferred to another tenant there is no impact to the services, but information about new tenant could take time to propagate (up to an hour). If you just transferred your subscription and see this error message, please try back later."
}
}
}

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my environment.

I am able to execute the same automation tasks for my Ubuntu VM successfully

> The access token is from the wrong issuer. It must match the tenant
> associated with this subscription. Please use correct authority to get
> the token

As per the error message, it appears to be a tenant Id mismatch issue.

Go to your Automation Task and under Authenticate, check which account is used as connection.

[image]

Make sure to use the account which you used to login to the Azure portal. That can fix the issue.

Comment: Hi, first thanks for your time. I have checked and I have used the same account in automated task authenticate as I use to login in Azure. By the way, its my only Microsoft account. Is there other idea to solve my problem?

Comment: Can you login to the VM using your account?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your account has multiple tenants, and Task Automation does not allow to select the correct one.

My suggestion is create a new Microsoft user account, grant it the permission to execute the task manually (in your example, deallocate the virtual machine), then select this user in Task Automation.